# Rails 4 ActiveRecord/Arel: Scoping models by their associated window's open/close date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app, backed by a Postgres database, I have an `Assignment` that `has_many :windows`. Each `Window` has an `open_date` and `close_date`.

Each `Window` model has three scopes:

```
scope :future,  -> { where(open_date.gt(Time.zone.now)) } 
scope :current, -> { where(open_date.lt(Time.zone.now).and(close_date.gt(Time.zone.now)))}
scope :past,    -> { where(close_date.lt(Time.zone.now)) }
```

In these scopes, `Window.open_date` and `Window.close_date` are arel methods defined as: `Window.arel_table[:open_date]` and `Window.arel_table[:close_date]` respectively.

My `Assignment` model has three scopes:

```
scope :future,  -> { joins(:windows).merge(Window.future) }
scope :current, -> { joins(:windows).merge(Window.current) }
scope :past,    -> { joins(:windows).merge(Window.past) }
```

---

Let's say a particular `Assignment` instance's `windows` query yields the following results:

```
-> assignment.windows
[#<Window
  id: "398b76fe-8a00-4c1b-8901-d040c5f236f6",
  open_date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 23:46:02 UTC +00:00,
  close_date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 23:46:02 UTC +00:00,
  assignment_id: "8b73b223-e48d-4cc0-8178-16eba9a5832b">,
 #<Window
  id: "08917f79-a9b0-41ce-a3ab-aa7821e23fba",
  open_date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 23:46:02 UTC +00:00,
  close_date: Wed, 12 Aug 2015 23:46:02 UTC +00:00,
  assignment_id: "8b73b223-e48d-4cc0-8178-16eba9a5832b">]
```

Both the `Assignment.current` and `Assignment.future` scopes will return this particular assignment in the result set since it has a current window and a future window.

I'd like this particular assignment to only show up when I make an `Assignment.current` call. I'd also like the `Assignment.future` scope to return assignments in which all windows are in the future.

Thanks for any help. Also, if anybody has a better title for this question, I'm open to suggestions :). Thanks.

Comment: So you're looking for `future` to only return records where `MIN(open_date)` is in the future?

Comment: Yes! Nice. What would be an organized way of doing that in rails?

Answer (score 0):

If you define the query conditions using strings, its fairly straightforward:

```
scope :future,  -> { joins(:windows).where("windows.open_date >= ?", Time.now) }
scope :current, -> { joins(:windows).where("? BETWEEN windows.open_date AND windows.close_date", Time.now) }
scope :past,    -> { joins(:windows).where("windows.close_date <= ?", Time.now) }
```